# Is there any difference between warning and warn in Golang's logrus?

Tags: go, logging

In logrus official doc, it just says below:

```
func Warn
func Warn(args ...interface{})
Warn logs a message at level Warn on the standard logger.

func Warning
func Warning(args ...interface{})
Warning logs a message at level Warn on the standard logger.
```

It looks like it's almost the same. Which one should I prefer to use?

Comment: They are exactly the same. Use whichever name you like more. Git blame didn't lead me to much insight on why it happened.

Comment: thanks Alex. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Warn and Warning are the same.

Check this
https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/blob/e4b0c6d7829bcf64435536c4a88f4088a3c76203/logrus.go#L44

Either of that two are ok but be consistent and use the same each time.

I use Warn because is shorter :)